# Re-evaluating native module sources error

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I am new to angular Cli, I am getting this error while installing and even when I start server by ng serve command:

> fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
>   Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
>
> Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.

Comment: What version of node.js?

Comment: node version:v6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a fatal error.  But you can always install watchman...